# Flutter Problems to launch app from Android studio to MacOs Simulator

Tags: macos, flutter

I try to launch a simply test app developed with android studio to IOS simulator on Mac Os System. From android studio i can launch the simulator but after if i try to run the app android studio don't find the simulator, where is the problem?
I attach many screen for show the version of software.
Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPpJc.png)

Comment: Can you add what shows in Logcat on Teminal, so to know what happened exactly

Comment: Hi,I attach the screen of the problem, thank you

Comment: I meant the error or what android studio tells you when you want to launch